# Amazon AWS. Migrating from Root Credentials to IAM Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm not sure which is the best way to do this. I have many projects hosted in Heroku, all of those projects use Amazon S3 for staticfile storage. All of them access the buckets using my Root Credentials (this is not safe, I want to change it). The Root Credentials are stored as Config Variables in each Heroku app.

I'd like to stop using Root Credentials and start using Amazon IAM Auth. I'm new to this. Should I create a `User` for each app? Or should create one User and let all the apps use that user credentials? Should I create a `Role` and give role the permissions to the buckets? Or, should I create a `Group`?.

Any advice will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a unique credential for each third-party application that you need to give access to. This way, you can revoke access independently. Also, each application is going to need different permissions. Having unique credentials for each service allows you to fine-grain the permissions.

If the third-party application (eg. Heroku) supports them, then create a cross-account IAM Role to give them.

1. Go to the "Roles" page.
2. Click "Create New Role".
3. Give the role a name.
4. Under "Role for Cross-Account Access", select "Allows IAM users from a 3rd party AWS account to access this account".

Only if they don't support cross-account IAM roles, create an IAM user for the service and create an access key to give to that service.

1. Go to the "Users" page.
2. Click "Create New Users".

An both cases, only give permissions for what they minimally need. **Never give admin, super-user, or all permissions to a third-party.** Avoid asterisks "*" where possible.

1. Find out from the third-party what permissions it needs. Ideally it would give you a policy to use.
2. **Review that policy.** Never blindly trust a third-party service.
3. Apply the policy to the user or role that you created.

Remember, you are granting access for someone else to read and/or modify your AWS account. Make sure you're not also granting them permission to destroy it.